# Why would the category of sets be intuitionistic?

Tags: set-theory, mathematical-philosophy, foundations, type-theory, intuitionism

This question is probably really naive. And, I hope the title doesn't come off as too combative. I think that topoi of $\mathbf{Set}$-valued sheaves provide an excellent motivation for higher-order intuitionistic logic, because most such topoi aren't boolean. But, I have an extremely hard time accepting that $\mathbf{Set}$ is intuitionistic.

Let me elaborate on this a bit.

Suppose our intuition for the phrase "subset of $X$" comes from the idea of having an effective total function $X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ that returns an answer in a finite amount of time. In this case, the subsets of $X$ ought to form a Boolean algebra.

Suppose on the other hand that our intuition for the phrase "subset of $X$" comes from the idea of having an effective partial function $X \rightarrow 1$, such that the program for $f(x)$ either halts in a finite amount of time, or else runs forever. Then, with a bit of thought, we see that subsets of $X$ should be closed under union and intersection. But also, there's really no way to take the complement of a subset in general. So, under this viewpoint, the subsets of $X$ form a bounded distributive lattice.

So, I'm willing to believe that $\mathbf{Set}$ is a Boolean topos (the classical viewpoint), and I'm also willing to believe that it's much, much less than that (the "algorithmic" viewpoint), because I think these are both well-motivated and reasonable positions.

The thing about trying to apply intuitionistic logic to $\mathbf{Set}$ is that it seems to straddle a very strange middle ground between these two extremes. It says: yes, you can take the complement of any subset. But no, it may not be the case that $A^c \cup A = X$ (where $A$ is a subset of $X$, and $A^c := X \setminus A.$). And, it may not be the case that $(A^c)^c = A.$ But nonetheless, you can be assured that $((A^c)^c)^c = A^c$. Huh? Look, I realize this makes perfect sense from a BHK perspective; for instance, the complement of the complement of $(0,1) \cup (1,2)$ is $(0,2)$. So, the double negation law fails. But, that's in a topological space! I mean, why would $\mathbf{Set}$ be subject to this kind of reasoning?

Comment: Concerning "really no way to take the complement" of a computably enumerable set: If you fix a theory, like say ZFC, then you might take the "complement" of a c.e. set $X$ to be the c.e. set of those $n$ such that ZFC proves $n\notin X$.  This is not an answer to your question because this notion of complement won't obey intuitionistic laws, and furthermore it depends on the specific algorithm for enumerating $X$. I mention it only because "really **no way** seems a bit too strong.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, that's a cool idea. Are you sure it won't obey intuitionistic laws?

Comment: Yes. Among other things, letting "$\sim x$" mean "Provably not x", it's not the case that $\sim(x \wedge \sim x)$ in general, by Goedel's Second Incompleteness Theorem (i.e., the falsum instance of Loeb's theorem).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You wrote:

> Suppose our intuition for the phrase "subset of $X$" comes from the idea of having an effective total function $X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ that returns an answer in a finite amount of time. In this case, the subsets of $X$ ought to form a Boolean algebra.

Unfortunately, this is not a workable intuition at all. If you insist that all subsets be classified by "effective total functions $X \to \{0,1\}$" then the subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are not even closed under countable unions and countable intersections. Or to put it another way, you are not allowed to say "for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$" and "there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$" in an unrestricted way. How then are we supposed to do any actual mathematics? For instance, number theorists would not even be allowed to *state*

> "For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is $k > n$ such that both $k$ and $k+2$ are prime."

without proving that there is a decision procedure which, on input $n$, decides whether there is a pair of twin primes above it. So, intuitionistic mathematicians *never* proposed such a view.

The idea that subsets be classified by termination of a partial effective procedure is equally unworkable, you just need to go one level up. It allows you to write statements of the form $\exists n \in \mathbb{N} . \phi(n)$ for decidable $\phi$, but not $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} . \phi(n)$.

*General* subsets are *not* classified by *any* kind of decision procedures, or semidecision procedures, or even procedures with access to oracles. You can always beat those with diagonalization to create more subsets. In computational terms, subsets should be thought of as being classified by completely arbitrary computational evidence. Then, among all the subsets *some* are classified by effective decision procedures (the *decidable* subsets), and *some* are classified by entirely uninformative computational evidence (those are the *complemented* subsets which are equal to their double complements).

Now, you ask why anybody would think of sets as intuitionistic objects. First of all, since you already subscribe to the idea that intuitionistic toposes make sense, you might be interested to know that every such topos begets an intuitionistic set theory, and vice versa, see [Relating first-order set theories and elementary toposes](https://doi.org/10.2178/bsl/1186666150) by Awodey et al. In this sense, the distinction between intuitionistic set theories and intuitionistic toposes (and intuitionistic type theories) is not all that important. It is known that we may often (but not always) pass between them as desired.

There are mathematical reasons for considering intuitionistic set theories, rather than toposes. For example, in theoretical computer science people tried to figure out how to do synthetic domain theory in toposes, and there were always some obstacles. In the end Alex Simpson switched to intuitionistic set theories to [solve some of the problems](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2003.12.005). Speaking a bit vaguely, he needed replacement *and* a non-trivial object $P$, or a set, with magical properties, such as $P$ containing $P^P$ as a retract. In classical set theory this is not possible due to cardinality reasons, but in intuitionistic set theory one can have such sets (and replacement). In topos theory there is no replacement.

Apart from the fact that there are good mathematical reasons for using intuitionistic set theories, one can also ask for philosophical or foundational reasons. I can only relate a personal view here. After having worked for some time with intuitionistic type theory and the internal languages of realizability toposes, I have definitely developed the idea that "bare sets", "bare types" and "bare objects" are not really just "bare collections of elements". They behave much more like topological spaces. The "intrinsic" topological structure of mathematical objects cannot be separated from the objects themselves. This point has been made by many people, but perhaps the most illuminating is the work of Martin Escardó, who puts the topological way of thinking to do surprising and interesting things in [functional programming](http://math.andrej.com/2007/09/28/seemingly-impossible-functional-programs/) and [type theory](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Emhe/papers/universe-indiscrete.pdf). Under this view the classical sets are just the "boring" intuitionistic sets. They are like the indiscrete spaces, and who would want to study those?

Once we subscribe to the idea that even the "bare sets" or "bare objects" may carry intrinsic structure, i.e., they are not just "Cantor's dust", then the double complement not being equal to the original is *the norm* rather than the exception. To give a couple of examples:

1. Suppose we work in presheaves on a category with two objects and two parallel arrows, which is just the topos of directed graphs. The double complement of a subgraph is not the original graph, but rather the full graph induced on the vertices of the original subgraph.
2. Suppose we work in a realizability topos, where an element of a subset carries computational evidence expressing *why* it is in the subset. Then an element $g$ of the subset $S = \{f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} \mid \exists x \in [0,1] . f(x) = 0\}$ of $[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ carries the computational evidence $\langle{p,q\rangle}$ where $p$ is a program for computing $g$ and $q$ is a program for calculating a real $a \in [0,1]$ such that $g(a) = 0$. An element of the double complement carries only $p$. Since $q$ cannot be algorithmically recovered just from $p$, the double complement is therefore not equal to the original.

We see here that double complement acts as a sort of regularization operation. In fact, that is precisely what it is in the topological interpretation of intuitionistic connectives: the complement of an open set $U$ in the topology is its exterior, and the double exterior of $U$ is its regularization. By observing that complements already are "regular" (the complement of a subgraph is a full subgraph, the complement of a subset has trivial computational evidence, the exterior of an open set already is regular) we come to *expect* that triple complements are the same thing as complements.

Comment: There can be replacement in topos theory: https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3802

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot about that paper of yours, good point.

Comment: This is a really good answer, because it shows that every last inch of my thinking about this issue is fraught with mistakes and problems. However, I object to the last paragraph... "Once we subscribe to the idea that mathematical objects carry intrinsic structure..." This seems to be a purely linguistic device for dodging the issue, or alternatively, you seem to be saying that you don't believe in underlying set functors. In either case, I don't think it really contributes to an otherwise excellent answer.

Comment: Lawvere is fond of pointing out that even for Cantor, _Mengen_ (=sets) weren't structureless (though Cantor of course used classical logic)

Comment: Well, the underlying set functor is there, of course. My point is that in many mathematical frameworks the natural idea of sets is that sets *do* have intrinsic structure that prevents them from being classical. You simply cannot remove it to get at the "classical underlying set", at least not without a lot of unnatural juggling.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I misinterpreted your point.

Comment: I rephrased a bit, is it clearer now? I do want to say something intelligent about double negation because the original question asks about it.

Comment: @AndrejBauer, yes, thank you. That's much clearer.

Comment: @AndrejBauer one might argue that the "classical underlying set" is the double-negation-sheafification...

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it could. I can see what it does in a realizability topos. What is it in a sheaf topos? Say over a space $X$. Something involving regular sets, does it have a name?

Comment: It's the restriction of a sheaf on $X$ to a sheaf on the largest dense sublocale of $X$, which is Boolean but has no points (hence its sheaves have no stalks).  I don't know a more explicit description.  (But in a cohesive topos, of course, it really is the underlying set in the obvious sense, equipped with the codiscrete structure.)

Comment: The link to the paper [Relating first-order set theories and elementary toposes](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=3561888280607584893) seems to be dead - in case it is useful for somebody, I will add at least in a comment [doi: 10.2178/bsl/1186666150](https://doi.org/10.2178/bsl/1186666150) and [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4493324) link. The paper is freely available here: https://www.math.ucla.edu/~asl/bsl/13-toc.htm

Comment: @MartinSleziak: thanks, I updated the link in the answer as well. By the way, I can edit other people's answers, can't you?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Thanks for the edit. Yes, I can edit your post. (Although I suppose that was a rhetorical question.) From several discussions on meta, it is clear that MathOverflow community is more sensitive about bumping old posts than other sites. That was a reason why I left only a comment. (If needed, we can continue this in chat - so that we don't leave here many comments unrelated to the actual post. Either [MO editors' loung](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2022/4/27) or [the room for broken links](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/135583/2022/4/27) would be fine.)

Comment: I don't think we need to discuss anything further, although I would be disappointed at people complaining about others performing community service, such as updating dead links.

Answer (score 11):

There are many answers that could be given, but I think the standard "algorithmically oriented" answer is the BHK/Curry-Howard interpretation, according to which a "subset $A$ of $X$" is specified by saying what a "proof of $x\in A$" means, for any $x\in X$, in such a way that whether or not something is such a proof is decidable (in finite time, algorithmically -- usually by a type-checking algorithm).  This is totally separate from the question of whether or not we have an algorithm that can *produce* such a proof (either decidably or semidecidably).

In particular, the "complement" $A^c$ is defined by saying that a proof of "$x\in A^c$" is (by definition of $A^c$) a proof that "$x\in A$" leads to a contradiction.  If we have a proof of $x\in A$, then by combining it with any proof of $x\in A^c$ we could get a contradiction, which is itself (by definition) a proof that $x\in (A^c)^c$; thus $A\subseteq (A^c)^c$.  Since the "complement" is inclusion-reversing, we also have $((A^c)^c)^c \subseteq A^c$, hence $((A^c)^c)^c = A^c$.

It's quite reasonable to object that this is not really a "complement".  Sometimes it is called a "pseudocomplement".  But whatever we call it, it's there.

Answer (score 5):

There's a third intuition: our intuition for subsets comes from the notion of *predicate* — a subset $S \subseteq X$ corresponds to the condition on $x \in S$ (for $x$ of type $X$).

The idea of subsets as characteristic functions $X \to \{ 0, 1 \}$ comes from ideas about *semantics*:

- Predicates on $X$ correspond to truth-valued functions on $X$
- $\{0, 1\}$ is the set of truth values

Of course, this only holds water if you already believe that truth is two-valued, which you don't if you disbelieve the mathematical universe is classical.

The topological character of truth turns out to follow naturally from an idea about what implication means:

> $P,Q \vdash R$ if and only if $P \vdash Q \to R$

Since we equate having two premises $P,Q$ with having a single premise $P \wedge Q$, it follows that the class of predicates on any object — and thus subsets of that object — is a Heyting algebra.

Since it's the very nature of **Set** that's under discussion, the Heyting algebra is automatically a complete Heyting algebra, and thus a *locale*.

---

All that said, my position is that foundations (and thus **Set**) are classical, and even if I were persuaded to someday go all-in with intuitionistic logic, it would be in the form of something like working exclusively in the internal language of a nonboolean topos.

Comment: Note that it is possible to be a constructivist and still require that there are only two truth values. The statements which are neither true nor false are not assigned a third invented truth value, but rather are *undetermined*; they demonstrate that truth predicates must be partial ala Tarski.